# Directly connect system call output to logger in Python

Tags: python, logging, call, stdout

I'm writing some code which involves running a few shell commands from Python and ideally, I would like to integrate the output from these commands into the logger that I'm using. I know I can divert stdout into a file / socket as follows:

```
call( '<a-shell-cmd>', shell=True, stdout=myFile )
```

but I'd rather not have the bind of opening a temporary file, looping over the file writing the output, closing the file, deleting the file etc. If there's anyway that I can send the output directly to the logger, it would seem a lot neater to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

Tip: you can go to the documentation for a particular version of python via `http://docs.python.org/release/<major>.<minor>/`

### From Python 2.7 and above:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["command", "arg1"], shell=True)
```

### In Python 2.4:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["command", "arg1"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout,stderr = process.communicate()
# not shown: how to use Popen.poll() to wait for process death.
# while filling an output buffer
print stdout
```

### Below Python 2.4:

```
output = os.popen('ls')
```

Comment: looks good, but I got this:`$ python Python 2.4.4 (#1, Jan 10 2007, 01:25:01) [C] on sunos5 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. >>> import subprocess >>> myOutput = subprocess.check_output( [ 'ls' ], shell=True ) Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in ? AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'`

Comment: Actually tried it on Python 2.6.2 as well but still no joy - same error.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the version specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Use os.popen

```
output = os.popen('ls')
```

You can then log output or do it directly when calling the above.